# CFCatch not catching a [SQLServer] Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have 3 separate environments with three different 'SA' passwords to the SQL Server. 
As this is the case, and for security, I am asking the user to supply the password:

```
<cftry>
    <cfquery name="runSQL" 
             datasource="#variables.dsn#" 
             username="sa" 
             password="#form.SQLPassword#"> 
         SQL Query 
    </cfquery>
    <cfcatch type="any">
       Error Wrong Password<cfabort>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

The problem is that if the user enters an incorrect password, I get a CF Error and it is not catching and displaying my message. How do I make it catch the incorrect login error? 
I am using Coldfusion 9.02 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: why on earth are you logging in as 'sa' ???

Comment: try not to focus on the loginname, it doesn't matter what I login in as the question is why it wont catch.

Comment: well, you're wrong there! You should NEVER be logging in as sa to read data. Ever. Period.

Comment: Please, that's not the QUESTION. try answering the actual question, it doesn't matter if its SA or not (I will change it, if it makes you feel better), i need to know why it wont catch?

Comment: `cfcatch` should catch a login failure error. Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16978222/edit) to include the full error message. *RE: ... it doesn't matter if its SA or not* Considering that even Microsoft discourages it, you should really review [some of the reasons why you should not use the sa account](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39124/why-should-an-application-not-use-the-sa-account).

Comment: Please include the error message that you are getting.